# Trouble parsing filename in expl3

Tags: expl3

I am trying to parse the file extension of a user-given path in expl3. I have got the file extension, but I can not manage to compare it to the expected file extension. My MWE is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g_slo_input_stream_ior
\tl_new:N \l_slo_input_dir_tl
\tl_new:N \l_slo_input_base_tl
\tl_new:N \l_slo_input_ext_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { V }

\cs_new:Nn \slo_open_file:n {
    \file_parse_full_name:nNNN { #1 } \l_slo_input_dir_tl \l_slo_input_base_tl \l_slo_input_ext_tl

    \tl_if_eq:VnTF \l_slo_input_ext_tl { .abc } { 
        #1~is~.abc-file.
    } { 
        #1~is~\l_slo_input_ext_tl-file,~expected~.abc-file.
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \abcfile } { m } { \slo_open_file:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \abcfile{example.test} \par
    \abcfile{filename.abc}
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
example.test is .test-file, expected .abc-file.
filename.abc is .abc-file, expected .abc-file.
```

while I expected

```
example.test is .test-file, expected .abc-file.
filename.abc is .abc-file
```

As far as I understand, the comparison in `\tl_if_eq` fails. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented, `\file_parse_full_name:nNNN` provides the 'retur' values as strings, not token lists. That is to say all characters have category code 12 ('other'), bar spaces which are category code 10 ('space'). The `tl` comparison checks tokens, so here category codes are important. Your literal '`.abc`' has category code 11 ('letter') `abc`, so the test fails.

Most of the time, and certainly here, you are likely better using the string-based tests for checking 'text'. This only look at character codes, so we don't have to worry about the category code business.

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \slo_open_file:n #1
  {
    \file_parse_full_name:nNNN {#1}
      \l__slo_input_dir_tl
      \l__slo_input_base_tl
      \l__slo_input_ext_tl
    \str_if_eq:VnTF \l__slo_input_ext_tl { .abc }
      { #1 ~is~.abc~file. }
      { #1~is~\l__slo_input_ext_tl-file,~expected~.abc-file. }
  }
```

Comment: I assume your variables are internal, so I've adjusted the names. Your function is not expandable, so I've made it `protected`. Also, I favour `\cs_new_protected:Npn` over the `:Nn` version ...